# google chrome extension - adding modules/plugins

Tags: frameworks, google-chrome-extension, modularity

I am starting to develop a an extension for google chrome, and i quickly realized that it will be almost imperative to have some kind of modularity.

However, i am unsure on what the best way to proceed would be.

Ideally, plugins should be easy enough to create and publish/share, even for non experts (given some sort of API), so i would rather avoid having them be other chrome extensions (with message passing, etc).

I have read a fair share of the docs and so far haven't found much helpful information, so any ideas are welcome

**Updated**

Sorry if i didn't make myself as clear as possible.
The main issues are:

1. Sharing aditional code ("plugins") without modifying/updating the extension.
2. Allowing custom code to be used without being publicly hosted (either privately or stored and evaluated?)

While both points go against each other, it would still quite possible to implement in a reasonable manner, if not for the security model implemented in google extensions...

Calling external code from within an extension (content script) doesn't seem to be possible by regular means, and neither is accessing the extension from the webpage context.

**New Updated**

Not enough coffee lately... i hope this is clear enough, and my apologies again.

I basically comes down to 2 choices:

1. Run new code (from source or url) in the context of the extension's content script (no idea how).
2. Inject new code into the webpage's document and implement message passing - i have looked into HTML5's MessageEvent and it would work, but with a lot of extra work.

**Thanks for the comments, I believe i have this mostly covered:**

- use a listener in background page that takes requests for scripts (urls are x-origin)
- set appropriate permissions in manifest ("tabs", "http://*/*")
- use localStorage for caching
- use chrome.tabs.executeScript to run code just as if part of the extension.
- Allow users to add new code (into localStorage)
- host some kind of 'plugins.json' file (description version, url, etc) for publishing new content for all the users

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by modularity exactly?

Comment: I have a main "core" script, and i will need to add random functionality to it. for this i've built a couple classes and a minimal API, but my issue is how to actually "link" to new user code, publish it, or allow users to add their own...

Comment: @jcinacio Do you want to let users adding code to their own installed extension, or let them make changes globally to all extensions installed worldwide?

Comment: I read your update and I still don't understand what you mean. But one thing for sure - extension sandboxing doesn't introduce any limitations that cannot be overtaken. Extensions allow you to do whatever javascript is capable of, and then some more. Do you know how to implement everything you described in regular javascript? If yes, then making extension out of it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: jcinacio, your question is vague, but it sounds like you're trying to create a system similar to Stylish/Userstyles, Greasemonkey/Userscripts, Google Chrome Extensions, or even Firefox Addons? Sounds like you want your extension to fetch code from a public depository website and save said code using `localStorage` (or let the user enter their code directly into local storage). Then you could inject the code as a Content Script when needed.

Comment: @Chris: I already have a working chrome extension, the injection is part is whats bothering me. How can i inject additional code that interacts with my extension (either content script, or background)?

Comment: @serg: users should change locally, but "global" (hosted) updates should be possible as well. that just means new script content should be possible to add from both urls and local storage.

Comment: `eval()` is the first what comes to mind for parsing js stored as strings (in localStorage?). If you have url to a script then you can always create `<script>` tag from it, or execute it in the content script (there is chrome api for this).

Comment: @serg: Thanks. eval() would obviously work. i always run away from it when possible, but i see no other choices here. I would also be simple to get the hosted code with ajax...

Comment: Instead of `eval()` you could use `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript. But certainly if you want a webpage's injected content script to communicate with your background page, message passing is needed: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html

Comment: Thanks. all i need is the executed script to communicate with the other content scripts (API), unless itself needs to do ajax.
I finally got x-origin requests working using the background page, so that shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: @jcinacio you should add an answer with the solution you came up with and mark this question as answered. You can read more about how in the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).